# performs a NAPTR query

Tags: dns, sip, srv

This may look like a very simple question, but I haven't found the answer on the Internet.

Anyone can give me clues how to performs a NAPTR query for a SIP domain? (this is mostly for DNS lookup), or any references also great for me (This one exist on rfc2915).

Maybe using terminal or any tools maybe and further i'd like to do it using java so if any piece of code will very helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The RFC you are looking for is "[Session Initiation Protocol (SIP): Locating SIP Servers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3263)".

Here's an abbreviated summary of how to select the transport protocol and resolve the SIP server address.

1. If transport parameter is specified it takes precedence,
2. If no transport parameter and target is an IP address then sip should use udp and sips tcp,
3. If no transport parameter and target is a host name with an explicit port then sip should use udp and sips tcp and host should be resolved using an A or AAAA record DNS lookup (section 4.2),
4. If no transport protocol and no explicit port and target is a host name then the client should do an NAPTR lookup and utilise records for services SIP+D2U, SIP+D2T, SIP+D2S, SIPS+D2T and SIPS+D2S,
5. If NAPTR record(s) are found select the desired transport and lookup the SRV record,
6. If no NAPTR records are found lookup SRV record for desired protocol _sip._udp, _sip._tcp, _sips._tcp, _sip._tls,
7. If no SRV records found lookup A or AAAA record.

In the real World virtually no SIP providers use NAPTR records, probably half or less use SRV records and the rest rely solely on A records. In my own SIP software I turned off the NAPTR lookup since it just wasted time and it's highly likely that if a SIP provider has bothered to set up NAPTR records they are also going to have set up the standard SRV records.

In hindsight the SIP protocol designers should probably have left the whole SIP server address resolution alone and let implementers use standard IP load balancing and failover mechanisms. Because SIP clients don't all support SRV records, again in my experience less than half, using such records is better than nothing but is not a great solution for failover or load balancing.

If you are looking for a hostname with SIP NAPTR records try columbia.edu and snom.com last time I checked they both had some.

Comment: hi sipwiz, tx for your answer it really makes me more understand coz i really new on this one. but i really want to know how to do the NAPTR lookup, let say i start at point 4 of your summary and i got this example.org as the fqdn. i actually lookin for some code here.

Comment: Doing an NAPTR lookup is the same as doing any DNS lookup you just specify a different record type. For example to do an NAPTR lookup using the Unix dig command is: dig columbia.edu NAPTR. My C# code that does SIP name server resolution is here http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/76924#299611.

Comment: Hi sipwiz, thanks for this DIG tool, by default this comes along in OSX terminal and also spread on the internet for windows version. And for java code there is library DNSJAVA http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava , and its pretty easy to implement. Thanks alot.

Comment: @dejoong if your code is using ENUM (the more common place where NAPTR records may be found) have a look for my "enumdroid" application on Google Code - it includes a generic RFC3401-5 DDDS implementation in Java.

Answer (score 2):

NAPTR records and SRV records are common in LTE (4G) solution. EPC nodes (network node) use DNS to select other EPC nodes using S-NAPTR & SRV records. This gives operator lot of freedom in adding/removing the nodes without changing any configuration on the MME node.  You can refer to some of the 3gpp standards 29.003 or 23.401 or google on the topic "epc node selections using DNS" . https://ericlajoie.com/nodeselection.html

Answer (score 1):

[A NAPTR record in DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAPTR_record) is just like any other record in [DNS (SRV, CNAME, etc.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types)

> NAPTR records are most commonly used for applications in Internet telephony, for example, in the mapping of servers and user addresses in the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP). The combination of NAPTR records with Service Records (SRV) allows the chaining of multiple records to form complex rewrite rules which produce new domain labels or uniform resource identifiers (URIs).
>
> The DNS type code for the NAPTR record is 35.

To query for them you can use the command line tool `dig` and specify the type of query using the `-t` switch. For example:

```
$ dig -t naptr 4.4.2.2.3.3.5.6.8.1.4.4.e164.arpa

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> -t naptr 4.4.2.2.3.3.5.6.8.1.4.4.e164.arpa
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64886
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;4.4.2.2.3.3.5.6.8.1.4.4.e164.arpa. IN  NAPTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
4.4.2.2.3.3.5.6.8.1.4.4.e164.arpa. 86400 IN NAPTR 100 20 "u" "E2U+pstn:tel" "!^(.*)$!tel:\\1!" .
4.4.2.2.3.3.5.6.8.1.4.4.e164.arpa. 86400 IN NAPTR 100 10 "u" "E2U+sip" "!^\\+441865332(.*)$!sip:\\1@nominet.org.uk!" .

;; Query time: 356 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.85#53(192.168.1.85)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 13 12:31:29 EDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 179
```

You can read more about E.164 & ENUM if you're interested:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164
- [A quick look at ENUM mapping telephone numbers to DNS](https://danielpocock.com/a-quick-look-at-enum)
- [Name Authority Pointer (NAPTR) RR](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/naptr.html)
- [Tutorial: SIP using NAPTR and SRV DNS Records](https://anders.com/cms/264/)
- [RFC2915](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2915)